# Saving data using ajax: sending large text in querystring is good or bad?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to add a comment feature in my ASP.NET website  that is similar in stackoverflow.com. Here the entire page is not getting posted, instead ajax is being used i hope.How does the value entered inside the textarea is passed to the server page ? as querystring for an ajax get/post call ? .I believe its not a good idea to do so when the content of the text area (text ) is large in size . How can i pass special characters  ?
Whats is the best method to do this ?  Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE has a size limitation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) for `get` requests. [This](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist) document is a good guide for choosing when to use `get` or `post`.

Answer (score 2):

Your instincts are correct.  You should only use QueryString for small things like ID's.  Use GET and POST for passing larger amounts of data.